# Django DRF Response returns "nested" array

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, return

I am trying to get json response from django server. Here are the views.py:

```
class RnDCalculationView(APIView):
     def get(self, request, format=None):
          qs = Model.objects.filter(...).values(...).annotate(all_hours=Sum('hours'), filtered_hours=Sum('hours', filter=Q(...)))
          return Response(qs)
```

If I get response from this endpoint I receive the correct data but they are nested in another array like this:

```
[
 [
  {
   "all_hours": 15,
  },
  {
   "filtered_hours": 5
  } 
 ]
]
```

Is there any way to get rid off one of the `[]` so the response will look like:

```
[
 {
   "all_hours": 15,
 },
 {
   "filtered_hours": 5
  } 
]
```

Comment: Are you using a serializer before returning the Response object?, I'm guessing that yes since you can't just send a queryset in a Response object.
can you post the full code for the get?

Comment: I do not use any serializer in this view.